# Invalid syntax error with lambda if/else in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe with a column called "body" that consists of various length strings. I also have a dictionary of acronyms that looks something like this:

```
dict acronyms = {
    'brb': 'be right back'
}
```

I'm trying to replace the acronyms in the dataframe with their actual meanings by looking if any of the key values of the dict is in the string and then replacing it with the value of that key.

```
df.body = df.body.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in acronyms.keys() else replace_acronym(word)]))
```

However, I get syntax error that is pointing to **else** part of the code. I don't understand what exactly is wrong with this code, could someone explain please?

The code for **replace_acronym(word)** function is:

```
def replace_acronym(acrn):
    return acronyms.get(acrn)
```

Comment: `' '.join(acronyms.get(word, word) for word in x.split())`…?!

Comment: @deceze thank you, this solves it! Still unsure why my code was throwing syntax error, though.

Comment: _"However, I get syntax error that is pointing to else part of the code"_ - please always include the full error message in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension works like:

```
[<put this in the list> for ... if <this condition is true>]
```

When the `if` condition is false, the element will be omitted from the resulting list. There is no `else`. What you mean is:

```
[<a> if <cond> else <b> for ...]
```

You want to put an `..if..else..` expression into the `<put this in the list>` part of the comprehension. So:

```
[word if word not in acronyms.keys() else replace_acronym(word) for word in x.split()]
```

Of course, this can be simplified a lot:

- `word in acronyms` is enough, that already checks for the existence of the key
- `replace_acronym(word) if word in acronyms else word` is easier than a negative condition
- since `replace_acronym` really doesn't do a whole lot, just do `acronyms[word] if word in acronyms else word`
- of course, this entire pattern is already encapsulated in `dict.get`, so: `acronyms.get(word, word)`
- the `[]` is superfluous if you're piping it into `' '.join` directly anyway, just use a *generator* expression instead:

```
' '.join(acronyms.get(word, word) for word in x.split())
```